# Can I specify the first namespace for ClojureScript compilation?

Tags: clojurescript

It seems that the ClojureScript compiler compiles files in `src` in alphabetical order. Is there a way to make it start with the `main` target instead? I currently include a file `aaa_init.cljs` in my projects which just happens to allow me to ensure certain things happen first... but this feels like an awkward solution.

It is useful to control the order that files are processed in so that I can ensure `(enable-console-print!)` happens before printing, and I can use conveniences like `defonce`, and re-frames `dispatch` to set initial values.

Answer (score 1):

Your question talks about two phases: compilation, and runtime. As far as I know, the order that you compile namespaces in will have no effect on runtime behaviour.

If you want `(enable-console-print!)` to be called before printing, or to dispatch initial values to re-frame, then those should happen in the `:main` function that you specify to the compiler. ClojureScript also has the ability to set [`:preloads`](https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#preloads) which run before your main function. These are typically more for development time tooling that you want compiled out of your production build, but could possibly be used for what you're asking.